# How do I resolve Unknown PdfException when using itext7 in. net maui

Tags: c#, maui, visual-studio-2022, itext7

Error returned on return:
Unknown PdfException. - - > System.NotSupportedException:Either itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter or itext7. bouncy-castle-fips-adap...
On line

```
Var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
```

My code is try to get create a pdf file using itext7 extension. In.net maui for mobile apps.

```
public static MemoryStream CreatePdf()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
                var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                var document = new Document(pdf);
                var paragraph = new Paragraph("hello");
                document.Add(paragraph);
                document.Close();
                stream.Position = 0;
                return stream;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider the complete message "System.NotSupportedException:Either itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter or itext7. bouncy-castle-fips-adap..." including the part cut off at the ellipse. Add the itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter or itext7. bouncy-castle-fips-adapter to your project.

Comment: @mkl This is not helpful without a reference to how to do so.

Comment: @Vladimir *"This is not helpful without a reference to how to do so."* - well, apparently the OP could add other iText modules to their project, so the hint above should tell them what to do.

Answer (score 38):

The reason it's occurring because from version 8.0, iText7 did several major breaking changes in the way they handle bouncy-castle dependencies. I assumed, your itext7 version is less than 8. So,

For resolving this issue, you need to install another Nuget package:

1. **Name:** itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter
2. **Link:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter

You can also check-out this answer, if you need more comprehensive solution including images.

- **Link:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168612/13861641

Comment: I use BouncyCastle 1.8.9 in my project for working with certificates and such. When I use this nuget, I get the error that itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter uses BouncyCastle 1.8.10 which is not available as a nuget. How is this error possible?

Comment: based on my understanding, you should uninstall your BouncyCastle 1.8.9 and try again.

Comment: This is so confusing. There is `itext.bouncy-castle-adapter` and `itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter`. They have the same version number, same published date, support the same frameworks and similar download numbers (sort or). On the website, they only mention IText Core. I'm lost... Which one of the adapter libraries do I choose?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using itext7 in a simple LinqPad script and encountered the problem after upgrading to Version 8. To get it up and runnnig again, I had to add references to:

- itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter (8.0.1)
- Portable.BouncyCastle (1.9.0)

A restart of LinqPad was also required. As mentioned already, this breaking change is documented [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/releases/release-itext-core-8-0-0/breaking-changes-for-itext-core-8-0-0/bouncy-castle-changes).